# Что такое временная сложность алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология, сложность

Что такое временная сложность алгоритма?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Временная сложность - это один из критериев оценки алгоритма. Под ней понимается зависимость итераций алгоритма от размера входных данных, т.е. это функция от N, где N это количество входных данных.

Comment: количества итераций

Answer (score 1):

Не количества итераций (это трудоемкость алгоритма), а именно время выполнения - это временная сложность.

Также есть энергетическая, экологическая, функциональная сложности.

Например, при одинаковых количествах итераций, алгоритмы умножения будут медленнее, чем алгоритмы сложения. То есть временнАя сложность будет разная...

Comment: Как минимум последнее утвержение неверно. Это вполне устоявшийся термин теории алгоритмов, не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: Умножение по времени одинаково со сложением? Давайте поговорим о методе Гибсона и операционном анализе... Я в курсе теории алгоритмов...

Comment: Мы не о секундомере говорим, а об оценке влияния размера задачи на время выполнения данного алгоритма. Говорить о временной сложности умножения и сложения без приведения алгоритмов некорректно.

Comment: Еще раз - сложности есть разные. Кол-во операций (операционная сложность) - это трудоемкость. Временная сложность - это время. Энергетическая - это энергия. Если два алгоритма содержат по две операции - то они имеют однинаковую трудоемкость. Но при разном времени выполнения операций будут иметь разную временнУю сложность. Зависит это не столько от алгоритма, сколько от исполнителя (ПК, процессора, контроллера и т.п.) В моих экспериментах самой медленной была операция деления - до 30 операций сложения

Comment: [Глава 6](http://cglab.ca/~michiel/TheoryOfComputation/TheoryOfComputation.pdf)

Comment: [Ну и ладно](http://www.nbuv.gov.ua/old_jrn/natural/emeo/2011_80/209-212.pdf)